# How to reskin android app while keeping the old one

Tags: android

So I made an android app for my highschool and it was a huge success, the other highschools want me to make it for them too. So my question is, how do I reskin the whole app while not losing the current one? My guess is that I just copy the entire project into a new folder and import it to eclipse and change the package name?

Comment: Take your original project and make it a library project/module.  Create a new project/module (application type) that depends on the first. then start overriding the styles& colors xml files in the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Take your original project and make it a library project/module. Create a new project/module (application type) that depends on the first. then start overriding the styles& colors xml files in the new project.